# notifications or posts with facebook Login using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

i am building a website with Facebook login. is it possible to send a post to my friends time line or notification to my friends using graph API. i want to build invite Facebook friends to my website. can some one help me on this

Comment: Posting code that you have researched / tried will fetch better results for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to the timeline of a friend was remove a long time ago, because it´s considered spam in most cases.

Notifications cannot be sent to friends either, luckily ;)

There are "App Requests", but they are only allowed for games on facebook.com and not for external websites.

The best (and easiest) way for you is to use one of the Social Plugins:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button